# How do I execute a node js file on MacOS?

Tags: node.js, macos

I've started the tutorial for Node.JS on tutorialspoint, but I can't get past the first step: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_first_application.htm

I us MacOS 10.13.5

I've created the following js file, named `main.js`.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

It's a copy-paste of the tutorial, but when I try to run the given command `node main.js` nothing happens.

When I write the code directly in the node CLI I get the following response:

```
Server {
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events:
   { request: [Function],
     connection: [Function: connectionListener] },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _connections: 0,
  _handle:
   TCP {
     reading: false,
     owner: [Circular],
     onread: null,
     onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
     writeQueueSize: 0 },
  _usingSlaves: false,
  _slaves: [],
  _unref: false,
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  pauseOnConnect: false,
  httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
  timeout: 120000,
  keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
  _pendingResponseData: 0,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  _connectionKey: '6::::8081',
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 192 }
```

**Edit:** 
The first time I tried writing it in the command line I misspelled response. I fixed it now and now I get the above response.

**Edit 2**
Here's what happens in the terminal. I included ls so you can see that it contains the file I'm trying to call
[image: Picture of terminal]

Comment: you have `respone` somewhere instead of `response`. check your code. the snippet looks fine, if that's all the code, ctrl+c and start the node again

Comment: **but when I try to run the given command node main.js nothing happens.** -- Didn't you see any output at all? Even the "server running" message?

Comment: @kiddorails I tried again in command line and now I only get the above server object as response

Comment: @Vasan I saw no output whatsoever

Comment: @Friso As kiddorails says the snippet is fine - I tried executing it and it works perfectly. Can you post a screenshot of your console on running the script?

Comment: u can't see the server running message ? what happens when you type "node" ?

Comment: @feiiiiii when I type node the node CLI opens and i can type code correctly in there, for instance if I type 1+1 I get 2 as a response

Comment: what about when you type "ls" what u see there ?

Comment: @feiiiiii I get a list of files, when I'm in the folder of my js file it's the only one, so I only see that one.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean , but you should only run node main.js inside the folder that contains your main.js

Comment: @feiiiiii Yes, I am in the folder where my main.js file is. When I type ls I see that it contains my main.js file.

Comment: and in this folder when you type "node main.js" you dont' see server running in terminal ?

Comment: @feiiiiii I added picture so you can see for yourself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173098/discussion-between-feiiiiii-and-friso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `ps -a | grep node` I saw I already had a process running. After I killed it I was able to execute my file.